# uninstall applications

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, uninstall

I have installed phpstorm , but after few minutes after installing it's uninstalled itself. But in `/usr/share/applications`, these files are still present:

```
JB-controlpanel.desktop              unity-sound-panel.desktop
JB-java.desktop                      unity-tweak-tool.desktop
JB-javaws.desktop                    unity-universal-access-panel.desktop
JB-jconsole.desktop                  unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop
JB-jvisualvm.desktop                 unity-wacom-panel.desktop
JB-mission-control.desktop           unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop
JB-policytool.desktop                update-accounts.desktop
```

What are they, and how do I delete them? 
Should I delete them before installing php storm again?

Comment: How do you know it deleted itself? What exactly happened?

Comment: I have installed , but after few times I couldn't open php storm

Comment: What do you mean cannot open? are all references to the program gone, or will it just not open? Are there any error messages?

Comment: just tell me how to delete files abowe

Comment: @kirgiz_jigit They're just java files, however it could be very critical if you delete them, i think.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't delete the files manually. First check the packages which contain the files. To do this in a clean way, install `apt-file` and test with `apt-file search` **and** `dpkg -S`.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Now create a simple file with the names of the desktop files,
in my example with the name **`foo`**, e.g.:

```
JB-controlpanel.desktop
JB-java.desktop                      
JB-javaws.desktop                    
JB-jconsole.desktop                  
JB-jvisualvm.desktop                 
JB-mission-control.desktop           
JB-policytool.desktop                
unity-sound-panel.desktop
unity-tweak-tool.desktop
unity-universal-access-panel.desktop
unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop
unity-wacom-panel.desktop
unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop
update-accounts.desktop
```

Now run an `awk` command to show the packages of each file with the command **`apt-file search`**:

```
awk '{printf "\n### %s ###\n",$1; system("apt-file search --regex /usr/share/applications/"$1"$")}' foo
```

Example output on my system:

```
$ awk '{printf "\n### %s ###\n",$1; system("apt-file search --regex /usr/share/applications/"$1"$")}' foo 

### JB-controlpanel.desktop ###

### JB-java.desktop ###

### JB-javaws.desktop ###

### JB-jconsole.desktop ###

### JB-jvisualvm.desktop ###

### JB-mission-control.desktop ###

### JB-policytool.desktop ###

### unity-sound-panel.desktop ###
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-sound-panel.desktop

### unity-tweak-tool.desktop ###
unity-tweak-tool: /usr/share/applications/unity-tweak-tool.desktop

### unity-universal-access-panel.desktop ###
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-universal-access-panel.desktop

### unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop ###
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop

### unity-wacom-panel.desktop ###
unity-control-center: /usr/share/applications/unity-wacom-panel.desktop

### unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop ###
unity-webapps-qml: /usr/share/applications/unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop

### update-accounts.desktop ###
unity-control-center-signon: /usr/share/applications/update-accounts.desktop
```

And the second test with `awk` and **`dpkg -S`**

```
$ awk '{printf "\n### %s ###\n",$1; system("dpkg -S "$1)}' foo

### JB-controlpanel.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-controlpanel.desktop*

### JB-java.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-java.desktop*

### JB-javaws.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-javaws.desktop*

### JB-jconsole.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-jconsole.desktop*

### JB-jvisualvm.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-jvisualvm.desktop*

### JB-mission-control.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-mission-control.desktop*

### JB-policytool.desktop ###
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *JB-policytool.desktop*

### unity-sound-panel.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-control-center:unity-sound-panel.desktop

### unity-tweak-tool.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-tweak-tool:unity-tweak-tool.desktop

### unity-universal-access-panel.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-control-center:unity-universal-access-panel.desktop

### unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-control-center:unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop

### unity-wacom-panel.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-control-center:unity-wacom-panel.desktop

### unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-webapps-qml:unitywebappsqmllauncher.desktop

### update-accounts.desktop ###
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-control-center-signon:update-accounts.desktop
```

In the first column you can see the name of the package, e.g. `unity-tweak-tool`, and **you should not** manually remove the files in the second column. You should delete the packages, if that's really necessary. But you could delete the files with no package, e.g. `JB-controlpanel.desktop` in the output above, with a command like this:

```
sudo rm JB-controlpanel.desktop
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between remove and purge

apt-get remove foo leaves the system configuration files.

apt-get purge foo removes the system files as well

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/apt-get.8.html

> remove
>              remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
>              instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its
>              configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to
>              the package name (with no intervening space), the identified
>              package will be installed instead of removed.

and purge

> purge
>              purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>              purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

Both options leave configuration files in $HOME however, you have to manually find and delete files in $HOME

Comment: I'm trying to remove them like this  **sudo apt-get remove JB-controlpanel.desktop**  but it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant to Phpstorm, Phpstorm is a proprietary package - which I don't believe is available through repos. The only way to get it is to download a zipped bundle from Jet Brain's website. Because its a self-contained (monolithic) package I  usually download and unzip it into `/opt`

Comment: Well, the OP should have explained how s/he installed the package if not with apt-get. I agree, if the package does not provide a method of removal, then one has to manually remove the files. In that event the OP should contact the people who packaged the application.

Answer (score 0):

> What are they?

```
JB-controlpanel.desktop     
JB-java.desktop             
JB-javaws.desktop           
JB-jconsole.desktop         
JB-jvisualvm.desktop        
JB-mission-control.desktop  
JB-policytool.desktop
```

These are Unity Launchers for Oracle Applications used for managing the Java virtual machine on which Phpstorm runs. The others, I guess are unity related.

> how do I delete them?

Like an ordinary file

> Should I delete them before installing php storm again?

I wouldn't unless you know what you are doing, in addition to being a convenience, the launchers sometimes contain necessary info for launching the application. For example - on Ubuntu - Phpstorm should be launched with some special options passed to it at invocation.
here is my `/usr/share/applications/phpstorm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Phpstorm_8.02
Exec=/bin/bash -l -c phpstorm
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-139.496/bin/webide.png
Type=Application
Categories=Developer;
Version=8.0
```

the `-l -c` switches avoid some undesirable behaviour in Phpstorm 8 - for example the grunt task runner feature won't work properly